# How to print column sub headings on specific columns dynamically?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to print column sub headings on some specific columns .. how can I print them dynamically?

Something like that ..

```
col heading 1     col heading 2     col heading 3
-------------     -------------     ------------------------- 
 col1    col2      col1    col2      col1   col2   col3   col4
```

Comment: It would help to show how you are storing/retrieving that information. Also, consider showing your attempts at a solution as it might be easier to explain it to you using your own code.

Comment: is there any possible way that the coloumn names in table like "abc def" "abc ghi" "abc jkl" are show in such a way that abc is consider as heading and under this, "def" "ghi " "jkl" are printed .. ??

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

    $recievedArray = array(array("abc def", "abc ghi", "abc jkl"),
        array("123 456", "123 789")); //Consider you getting the result from db to php as array

    /**
     * 
     * @param array $array Two dimentional array to format
     * @return string
     */
    function formatter(Array $array)
    {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $sub = '';
        foreach ($value as $subKey => $subValue) {
            $sub .= strstr($subValue, ' '); //Get string after first space
            $exploded[strstr($subValue, ' ', TRUE)] = $sub; //Get string before first space
        }
    }

    $html = '';
    $tableStart = '<table>';
    $tabeEnd = '</table>';
    $th = '';
    $td = '';
    $lineTd = '';
    $trStart = '<tr>';
    $trEnd = '</tr>';

    //Here th and td are prepared
    foreach ($exploded as $key => $value) {

        $th .= '<th>' . $key . '</th>';
        $lineTd .= '<td>' . str_repeat('--', strlen($value)) . '</td>';
        $td .= '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
    }

    //Concatenate the string to get the formated table data
    $html .= $tableStart .
            $trStart .
            $th .
            $trEnd .
            $trStart .
            $lineTd .
            $trEnd .
            $trStart .
            $td .
            $trEnd .
            $tabeEnd;

    return $html;
    }

    echo formatter($recievedArray);
```